# How to export and import directories as variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

First script takes input from user of a directory:
eg:D:\Test1
D:\Test2

```
$Dir1=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter first location" |Out-file -FilePath .\directories.csv -Append
    $Dir2=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter 2nd location (or leave blank)" |Out-file -FilePath .\directories.csv -Append
```

In the second script I have:

```
$Dir=Import-Csv 'D:\directories.csv'
$Dir[0]
```

But it doesn't print out correctly (prints all directories instead of just one)
I need to assign each directory to a different variable

P.S. Total beginner here so please explain briefly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take:

Prompt for paths in loop and collect in array until no entry:

```
$DirPaths = @()
Do {
    $DirPaths += Read-Host -Prompt "Enter path (leave blank to end)" 
} Until ($DirPaths[-1] -eq '')
```

Save all elements but the empty string to a text file:

```
$DirPaths.Where({ $_ -eq '' }, 'Until') | Set-Content .\DirPaths.txt
```

With a sngle element per line & no header row, there's no need for a .csv

Use `Get-Content` to retrieve the file as an array of paths

```
$Dir = Get-Content .\DirPaths.txt
```

Then you can obtain a count of paths and access individually like so:

```
$Dir.Count
$Dir[0]
```

### Example:

```
>$DirPaths = @()
>> Do {
>>     $DirPaths += Read-Host -Prompt "Enter path (leave blank to end)"
>> } Until ($DirPaths[-1] -eq '')
Enter path (leave blank to end): Path1
Enter path (leave blank to end): Path2
Enter path (leave blank to end): Path3
Enter path (leave blank to end):
PS C:\...\Sandbox>$DirPaths.Where({ $_ -eq '' }, 'Until') | Set-Content .\DirPaths.txt
PS C:\...\Sandbox>$Dir = Get-Content .\DirPaths.txt                                     PS C:\...\Sandbox>$Dir.Count
3
PS C:\...\Sandbox>$Dir[0]
Path1
PS C:\...\Sandbox>
```

### Edit:

This code uses the `BrowseForFolder` method:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$Folders = @()
Do {
    $Folders += $Shell.BrowseForFolder( 0, 'Prompt', 0, 17 )
} Until ( $Null -eq $Folders[-1] )

$Folders.Self.Path | Set-Content .\DirPaths.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I modified it a bit and got it to pop out file explorer in the do-loop  to select directory instead of just using Read-Host. Now, I just need to know how to terminate it {Until ($Dir[-1] = '' or 'Cancel')} doesn't seem to work. Also, I don't need to worry about extra text in the outfile because I figured out a way to read only specific lines in a pattern

Comment: I haven't played much with Forms, but I added a code sample that uses `Shell.Application.BrowseForFolder()` method. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

Based on the comments, what the author wants to achieve is to get the selected directories in string format and due to the functions they select, the directories end up in table format and thus complicate the problem. Here are two scripts that

1. you can use to get two directories from a `FolderBrowserDialog` and save them into a text file.
2. you can use to get the directories from the text file and print to console.

**Script 1**

```
#function for the directory selection dialog
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="")
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

#call open dialog twice
for($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++){
    $a = Get-Folder
    $a | out-file -append directory.txt
}
```

**Script 2**

```
#print each directory into the console
foreach($line in Get-Content .\directory.txt) {
    $line
}
```

### Old answer

Import-Csv is assuming the first line of your csv file is a header so in this case `D:\Test1` is assumed to be the header. Since your file is missing the header you can input the header manually to avoid that problem.

`$Dir=Import-Csv 'D:\directories.csv' -Header "DummyHeader"`

Now `$Dir[0]` will print out correctly (The header will always be shown here).

Comment: When I use "Export-csv" it is storing the length (number)  but not the directory itself. So I tried Out-File which stores the directory location but it comes with the header everytime I call it. Which puts out errors for copying and moving commands. Either need to store the dir itself by using Export-csv or call dirs without headers using Out-File

Comment: After a bit of digging, I've found that ConvertTo-csv could get the job done but I'm not sure how or where to use it. So, would appreciate if you could guide me (I have already checked Get-Help ConvertTo-csv)

Comment: @AbP it seems that you want to do other work after this problem. It might help if you can show us the full picture so we can better formulate the answer.

Comment: @AbP I see. So csv format is probably not necessary. In script 2 you can just read it as normal text file. I'm not at my PC so here's a quick answer from other people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511772/read-file-line-by-line-in-powershell. In your case, each line will be each of your directories so not much else needs to be changed.

Comment: Normal txt file also comes with headers or "category" which puts out errors

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sp7HvMM8 This is how Text file comes out (after implementing getting file explorer to help user choose dir) Ik all the useless lines can be eliminated but it still leaves me with "Selected Path" in the same line as the dir @lin

Comment: @AbP I've updated the answer.